# Hide javascript folder on server

Tags: javascript

I've noticed on some sites, when I go to eg. www.example.com/js where there javascript is stored, it is forbidden.

On my website currently, if users browse to www.mysite.com/js they will see all of my javascript files nicely arranged into folders. How can I prevent them from browsing this directory and still keep my javascript working correctly?

PS. I know the user downloads the javascript when they use my site and there is no way to prevent someone from reading the source but I would like to prevent what I am describing, as I see other sites have achieved this.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a webserver setting. The exact answer depends on the webserver make/version used. Please mention which one you're using.

Comment: It is Linux hosting with cPanel Control. is that what you mean?

Comment: Not exactly, but in ~90% of such hosts they're using Apache HTTPD.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache here is some helpful documentation:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/200607.mbox/%3C44A8C1F3.3000007@wmk.ch%3E

http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml

Answer (score 1):

> It is Linux hosting with cPanel Control. is that what you mean?

It's likely using Apache HTTPD server. Drop a `.htaccess` file in the JS folder with the following content:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will disable directory indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, all of those people's answers are totally good and valid.

However, there's a much, much, much simpler way of acheiving this:

1. Create a blank text file inside the JS folder called `index.html`
2. ???
3. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question for ServerFault, but you should be able to forbid directory indexes in the /js directory.  You could also block access from browsers that don't present a referrer string in your site, though that might break some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

use the .htaccess sent below, =]
... and you can compress your js files to improve the performance and to ensure the "privacy" of your scripts too:

http://javascriptcompressor.com/

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/